# how to import existing VM in vmware workstation 8 inventory

Tags: vmware-workstation

I like to add existing vmware (player) virtual machines to the vmware workstation 8 inventory on linux. When I create a new virtual machine, it is stored in `/var/lib/vmware/Shared VMs/`. But copying new directories to that folder, does not make them appear in the workstation window.

I found out, the inventory is stored in `/etc/vmware/hostd/vmInventory.xml`;

```
<ConfigRoot>
  <ConfigEntry id="0000">
    <objID>1</objID>
    <vmxCfgPath>/var/lib/vmware/Shared VMs/test 1234/test 1234.vmx</vmxCfgPath>
  </ConfigEntry>
</ConfigRoot>
```

But I don't know if I break anything when adding entries myself, and giving it an unique ID. Besides, adding a large number of VMs this way is a bit cumbersome.

On ESX, it [was possible](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006160) to use `vmware-cmd -s register`, but I don't have a `vmware-cmd` installed. In [another question](https://superuser.com/q/234951/57579) it was suggested to use vmware converter. But vmware converter 5 (on windows) only allows a destination file location when I select workstation as destination type. When I select vmware infrastructure as destination type, it says the destination is unsupported; it required vmware vcenter server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just open the VMX file with VMware Workstation. It will add it to the inventory.

Comment: That will add it to `~/.vmware/inventory.vmls`, but not to `/etc/vmware/hostd/vmInventory.xml`. It is also not visible in the list of VMs to automatically start when the host starts.

Comment: However I can choose Manage>Share after opening it. I'll do some tests with it.

Comment: It is working, however it is not possible to share a VM which is suspended. So it only works for VMs which are completely shut down.